# In Jurassic, how do I limit script running time?

Tags: javascript, c#, jurassic

I am implementing Jurassic script engine, how do I limit how long a script will take?

```
    string ExcutingFunction = " for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++){ i%2; } ";
    ScriptEngine  ScrptingEngine = new ScriptEngine();
    ScrptingEngine.Execute(ExcutingFunction);
```

Comment: what do you mean limit how long a script will take? like time out if it's taking to long?

Comment: Like stop the script if it take too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jurassic does not have an built-in way to limit the execution time of a script. Because Jurassic compiles JavaScript methods into IL code, there is no easy way to provide a timeout functionality without affecting performance.
>
> However, it is possible to use `Thread.Abort()` to raise a `ThreadAbortException` in the thread that executes the script. One possibility is to run `ScriptEngine.Execute()` in a new thread and call `thread.Abort()` in the current thread if the new thread does not complete after a specific time.

[Source](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic/wiki/Safely-executing-user-provided-scripts#limiting-execution-time)

If you read through the documentation, they do have suggestions for how to do this but it is a bit lengthy and involved.